# Pageable - sorting for constants and variables type

Tags: java, spring-boot, pageable

I'm getting a list of objects from the database. I use Pageable for the page, number of elements, etc.
Now I need to always have objects of a given type at the beginning of the list (type = "Media") and then other types of objects. And I want to continue sorting them, e.g. by the name of the object, so that again objects of the Media type are displayed first, and then others. Is it possible to set Pageable to return such results to me (or is there another option)?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your Repository by extending PagingAndSortingRepository.

Then you can provide multiple Sort by attributes which you want to use.

for e.g

```
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository 
        extends PagingAndSortingRepository<EmployeeEntity, Long> {

}

Sort emailSort = Sort.by("email"); 
Sort firstNameSort = Sort.by("first_name");
Sort multipleSort = emailSort.and(firstNameSort);

Pageable paging = PageRequest.of(pageNo, pageSize, multipleSort));
Page<EmployeeEntity> pagedResult = repository.findAll(paging);
```

Please check  :: https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/pagination-sorting-example/

Comment: I just don't quite like it. There are 5 types: Audio, Folder, Media, Text, Video. If I do sort by type (Sort.by("type)), then sorting will occur where objects with the type Audio or Video will be returned first. And I would like it to be returned first Media and then others.

Comment: By default it's ascending order. And it will use the value to sort.

Comment: can you try using @SortComparator(CustomComparator.class)
List<EmployeeEntity> findAll(Pageable pageable);